# how do I convert if else to one line if else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how do i convert follow code to one line if else

```
if (data.BaseCompareId == 2)
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt"));
else
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt"));
```

i try this code but did not work

```
data.BaseCompareId == 2
    ? report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt"))
    : report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt"));
```

Comment: How did it not work? Didn't it compile? Or didn't it produce expected results?

Comment: Don't use the ternary operator (?:) in this case. You don't gain anything and just make your code less readable.

Comment: I don't understand why you mention "one line" since you spread your ternary operator over three lines. You *could* put an `if` on a single line if you wanted to: just remove the line breaks!

Answer (score 5):

Try with this instead :

```
string path = data.BaseCompareId == 2
    ? "~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt"
    : "~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt";
report.Load(Server.MapPath(path));
```

Since report.Load() returns a void, it wont work.

Edited version :

```
string s = data.BaseCompareId == 2 
      ? "MonthGroup.mrt" 
      : "YearGroup.mrt";
report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/" + s));
```

Comment: A good answer, but please see the answer by @helb for an improved implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming `report.Load` returns a void, hence it "doesn't work".  That said, why are you doing this?  The first example is perfectly clear.

Comment: Agreed - why do this? First example is clear, second way makes you read it a couple of times.

Comment: If one wishes to employ the "Do not repeat yourself" (DRY) principle, then the first case is poor, as it duplicates `report.Load(Server.MapPath(...`.

Comment: @DavidArno, so does his second case ;)

Comment: That's why I favour @helb's answer as that avoids such duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a ternary operator, you can do:

```
report.Load(data.BaseCompareId == 2 ? Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt") : Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt"));
```

Or (better):

```
report.Load(Server.MapPath(data.BaseCompareId == 2 ? "~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt" : "~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt"));
```

(Or you could further exploit the similarity in the two strings, as @helb's answer does.)

As has already been noted, your way doesn't work because you're trying to replace a conditional statement with a conditional expression, and conditional expressions have to have a *value*. Since `report.Load` apparently returns `void`, a conditional expression of the form `cond ? report.Load(...) : report.Load(...)` doesn't have a value, ergo it doesn't work.

Each of the ways above will work because the conditional expressions in them have values - in the first case, the value will be of the type returned by `Server.MapPath`; in the second case, the value will be of type `string`.

As to whether you *should* do this: there are arguments to be made either way. The original way has the advantage of being clear and simple, but it does involve some (arguably undesirable) repetition. The latter approach above has the advantage of only saying things once and emphasising the intent of the whole statement (to load a report), but it's arguably slightly less clear than the original, depending on how used people are to seeing conditional expressions. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you want are going to use ?: here use it so only the part which is *actually different* is in the branching statement:

```
string fileName = (data.BaseCompareId == 2) ? "MonthGroup.mrt" : "YearGroup.mrt";
report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StimulReports/" + fileName));
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO as you have zero code duplication. However, some folk seem to find the ternary operator hard to read and still might favour the OP's original code. +1 from me though.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is just for cases where it returns something. So you could do something like:

```
var path = (data.BaseCompareId == 2) ? "~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt" : "~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt";

report.Load(Server.MapPath(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most concise I could get for a one-liner...

```
report.Load(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Content/StimulReports/{0}Group.mrt", data.CompareId == 2 ? "Month" : "Year")));
```

However, it seems you just want to make things look cleaner.
More abstraction between data calls and the conditional logic.
You might want to consider making them separate methods, perhaps on your report object?

```
if(data.CompareId == 2)
    report.LoadStimulReports(ReportGroup.Month);
else
    report.LoadStimulReports(ReportGroup.Year);
```

Using an enum, extension method, and static method on your report object...

```
public enum ReportGroup
{
    [DescriptionAttribute("~/Content/StimulReports/MonthGroup.mrt")]
    Month,
    [DescriptionAttribute("~/Content/StimulReports/YearGroup.mrt")]
    Year
}

public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum e) where T : Attribute
{
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = e.GetType().GetField(e.ToString());
    object[] o = (object[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
    return o.Length > 0 ? (T)o[0] : default(T);
}

public static void LoadStimulReports(ReportGroup reportGroup)
{
    report.Load(Server.MapPath(reportGroup.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));
}
```

Now you can simply add another item to the enum if you need another report.

```
[DescriptionAttribute("~/Content/StimulReports/WeekGroup.mrt")]
Week
```